# Using junit in ant

Tags: java, ant, junit

I am trying to run my tests using junit,
compile returns success, but when I run it, i get this error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Homewok2Test.class
```

Here is my build.xml:

```
<project name="othello" basedir=".">
    <target name="compile">
      <javac srcdir="src" destdir="build">
         <classpath>
            <pathelement path="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
            <pathelement path="lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/> 
         </classpath>
       </javac>
       <jar jarfile="dest-client/othello-client.jar"   basedir="build">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Homewok2Test.class" />
        </manifest>
       </jar>
     </target>
    <target name="run">   
        <java jar="dest-client/othello-client.jar" fork="true"/>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Is it really called "Homewok"? And do you really need to use the ".class" suffix?

Comment: File with test class is called Homework2Test, if I dont use the suffix I get the same error

Comment: So maybe referring to a class called "Home**wok**2Test" won't work then.

Comment: I think its because there is not main in Homework2Test, there is only test class `public class Homework2Test` for junit, but how can I add junit?

Comment: See my answer. I've updated it to show you how to run JUnit from within Ant. If you don't, then you're going to have to add a main method in Homework2Test and then call JUnit from within that method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amend this...

```
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="Homewok2Test.class" />
```

To...

```
<attribute name="Main-Class" value="Homework2Test" />
```

NB your value above has a typo, which could be another issue for you: **Homewok**.

And ensure that your Homework2Test class has a main method something like this...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    org.junit.runner.JUnitCore runner = new org.junit.runner.JUnitCore();
    org.junit.runner.Result result = runner.run(Homework2Test.class);
}
```

The value is the fully qualified package path to your class, not the physical class file path. Then when you run the jar, it will automatically pick up the Main-Class attribute and run that class accordingly.

If you're running your JUnit tests from your Homework2Test class, then everything should be fine, but if you're not, then you may wish to run JUnit from Ant.

Something like this...

```
<target name="unit-test-1" >
  <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="${project.class.path}"/>
      <pathelement location="${build.tests}"/>
      <pathelement path="${java.class.path}"/>
    </classpath>
    <test name="com.jenkov.test.MyUnitTest"
             haltonfailure="no" outfile="result">
      <formatter type="plain"/>
      <formatter type="xml"/>
    </test>
  </junit>
</target>
```

**Taken from [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-unit-testing/running-tests-with-ant.html)**

Or [this tutorial](https://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html) may also be of use.

Comment: I get the same error. I am not sure if I use the junit the right way, because run want some main class, but in my test there is no main class only `public class Homework2Test`

Comment: My assumption is that you're running your JUnit test classes from that main Homework2Test class? If not, then you're going to have to specify running JUnit from your Ant build.xml file. See [THIS](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html), for info on how to do that.

Comment: I am not sure what I should type to "${project.class.path}" and "${java.class.path}"

Comment: You can set those up as properties at the top of your build.xml file, underneath the project level. E.g. `<property name="java.dir" value="\java" />`. You're going to need to read up on Ant a bit here and how to code a build.xml file.

Comment: I understand the properties, but I am not sure what values it should have, since I have src/ folder , where are .java files, and then build/ folder where are .class files , and dest-client/ folder where is .jar file

Comment: I've updated my answer again to give you more info. You either need to call JUnit from your main method (probably simplest for you). OR, you need to set it up from your build.xml file. But you'll need to understand how Ant works to do that. I've given examples of both above for you to choose what suits you best.

Comment: I need the ant solution, I must go deeper . Anyway thanks

Comment: You don't have to use properties BTW, you can just directly enter the values required to make it run. But, yes, you'd be best to go deeper into some Ant tutorials here. It's well worth the effort. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 0):

So I added

```
 <target name="run">   
            <junit printsummary="yes" haltonfailure="yes">
                <classpath>
                    <pathelement path="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
                    <pathelement path="lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
                    <pathelement path="dest-client/othello-client.jar"/>
                    <pathelement location="lib/junit-4.12.jar"/>
                    <pathelement location="lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
                    <pathelement location="dest-client/othello-client.jar"/>
                </classpath>
                <test name="Homework2Test" haltonfailure="yes" outfile="result">
                    <formatter type="plain"/>
                    <formatter type="xml"/>
                </test>
            </junit>
<target/>
```

Next problem was spelling, in my first build I have Homewok2Test, which is incorrect. Correct class was Homework2Test